# The post method is not supported for this route

Tags: html, laravel, eloquent

I'm new to laravel and I want to submit a form which have three attachments plus some arrays

but when I click submit button laravel says

> "The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD."

I've searched a lot but couldn't find any errors

My View

```
<div>
    <form action="insertquotation" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        <table border="1" id="formTable">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>procurment_request_number</td>
                <td>quotationer</td>
                <td>shop_name</td>
                <td>shop_account_number</td>
                <td>shop_permit</td>
                <td>shop_quatation</td>
            </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="procurment_request_number" id="procurment_request_number" value="{{$result->first()->request_number}}">
                    {{--<select name="procurment_request_number[]" id="procurment_request_number">--}}
                        {{--@foreach($result as $results)--}}
                            {{--<option value="{{$results->request_number}}">{{$results->request_number}}</option>--}}
                            {{--@endforeach--}}
                    {{--</select>--}}
                </td>
                <td><input type="text" id="quotationer1" name="quotationer1"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="shop_name1" id="shop1_name"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="shop_account_number1" id="shop1_account_number"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="shop_permit1" id="shop1_permit"></td>
                <td><input type="file" accept="application/pdf" name="shop_quatation1" id="shop_quatation"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="quotationer" name="quotationer2"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="shop_name2" id="shop1_name"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="shop_account_number2" id="shop1_account_number"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="shop_permit2" id="shop1_permit"></td>
                <td><input type="file" accept="application/pdf" name="shop_quatation2" id="shop_quatation"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="quotationer" name="quotationer3"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="shop_name3" id="shop1_name"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="shop_account_number3" id="shop1_account_number"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="shop_permit3" id="shop1_permit"></td>
                <td><input type="file" accept="application/pdf" name="shop_quatation3" id="shop_quatation"></td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Item_ID</td>
                    <td>Quantity</td>
                    <td>Unit_ID</td>
                    <td>description</td>
                    <td>Shop1_price</td>
                    <td>Shop2_price</td>
                    <td>Shop3_price</td>
                </tr>
                @foreach($result as $results)
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="itemid[]" id="itemid" value="{{$results->id}}"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" id="quantity" value="{{$results->quantity}}"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="units_id[]" id="units_id" value="{{$results->units_id}}"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="description[]" id="description" value="{{$results->description}}"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="shop1_price[]" id="shop1_price"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="shop2_price[]" id="shop2_price"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="shop3_price[]" id="shop3_price"></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            @endforeach
        </table>
        {{--<input value="addrow" type="button" id="addrow"  onclick="javascript: addRow();">--}}
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

My Controller

```
public function insertquotation(request $request)
{
    if ($file = $request->file('shop1_quatation')) {
        $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move('procurement_files', $name);
        $file2 = $request->file('shop2_quatation');
        $name2 = $file2->getClientOriginalName();
        $file2->move('procurement_files', $name2);
        $file3 = $request->file('shop2_quatation');
        $name3 = $file2->getClientOriginalName();
        $file3->move('procurement_files', $name3);
        $procurment_request_number = $request->input('procurment_request_number');
        $quotationer1 = $request->input('quotationer1');
        $quotationer2 = $request->input('quotationer2');
        $quotationer3 = $request->input('quotationer3');
        $shop_name1 = $request->input('shop_name1');
        $shop_account_number1 = $request->input('shop_account_number1');
        $shop_permit1 = $request->input('shop_permit1');
        $shop_name2 = $request->input('shop_name2');
        $shop_account_number2 = $request->input('shop_account_number2');
        $shop_permit2 = $request->input('shop_permit2');
        $shop_name3 = $request->input('shop_name3');
        $shop_account_number3 = $request->input('shop_account_number3');
        $shop_permit3 = $request->input('shop_permit3');
        $numbers = $request->input('itemid');
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($numbers); $i++) {
            $itemid = $request->input('itemid');
            $shop1_price = $request->input('shop1_price');
            $shop2_price = $request->input('shop2_price');
            $shop3_price = $request->input('shop3_price');
            DB::insert("INSERT INTO procurment_quotations (`procurment_request_number`, `itemid`, `quotationer1`, `quotationer2`, `quotationer3`, `shop1_name`, `shop1_account_number`, `shop1_permit`, `shop1_quatation`, `shop1_price`, `shop2_name`, `shop2_account_number`, `shop2_permit`, `shop2_quatation`, `shop2_price`, `shop3_name`, `shop3_account_number`, `shop3_permit`, `shop3_quatation`, `shop3_price`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,)", [$procurment_request_number, $itemid[$i],$quotationer1,$quotationer2,$quotationer3,$shop_name1,$shop_account_number1,$shop_permit1,$name,$shop1_price,$shop_name2,$shop_account_number2,$shop_permit2,$name2,$shop2_price,$shop_name3,$shop_account_number3,$shop_permit3,$name3,$shop3_price]);
        }
    }
}
```

and my route

```
Route::Post('insertquotation','Home@insertquotation');
```

The error is

> "The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD."

Comment: Change `Post` to  `post` in your route file

Comment: post is case sensitve try changing it so `Route::Post('insertquotation','Home@insertquotation');`  to `Route::post('insertquotation','Home@insertquotation');`

Comment: action="{{ route('insertquotation') }}"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the route a name in your *routes/web.php* file:

```php
Route::post('insertquotation','Controllername@methodname')
    ->name('insertquotation');
```

And then change the form action in your blade file to point to that route:

```html
<form action="{{ route('insertquotation') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: now it say's "Route [insertquotation] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\procurement\resources\views\quotation.blade.php)

Comment: That's because `route()` function is to generate URL based on route name. change `route()` to `url()`

Answer (score 2):

I think from `action="insertquotation"`, you should make it into `action="{{url('insertquotation')}}"`

And may I see the codes in your `routes/web.php` file? you should declare the route `insertquotation` there

For example:

```
Route::post('insertquotation', 'YourController@yourMethod');
```

Comment: action="{{ route('insertquotation') }}"

Comment: the only time he'll be using the "route" helper is when he'll be naming the routes, by adding the code **->name('inserquotation');** but it would be redundant coz that's the declared route, and he will name it also as "inserquotation"?

Comment: it gives error like this ""Route [insertquotation] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\procurement\resources\views\quotation.blade.php)"

Comment: I think you're missing some codes to show us, where can we find tat you have indicated the view named **quotation.blade.php** ?

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things which I need to point out on your code

It is always better to use route names while creating routes so that when you need to change the route URL to something else, you only need to change it inside routes file (not view files)

```
Route::post('insertquotation','Home@insertquotation')->name('insertquotation');
```

Now inside your view, you need to do this

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ route('insertquotation') }}"> ... </form>
```

In the future when you want (maybe not) to change the URL to `/quotation/insert`, all you have to do is to change it inside the routes file.

Now, inside your controller,

There is a function to check whether the file exists `$request->hasFile('shop1_quatation')` which more correct to use inside an if condition rather passes in the file.

Also, it is much better to use Laravel eloquent for inserting data into the database. [Learn more here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent)